# ideas for displaying big amount of json values in a bootstrap table

Tags: php, jquery, json, yii

this is my Json That i encoded in controller as an array

```html
{"allk":[{"name":"raju","designation":"developer","address":"he is from viswasapuram","salary":"30000"},{"name":"bob","designation":"designer","address":"no idea","salary":"100000"},{"name":"bob","designation":"designer","address":"no idea","salary":"100000"},{"name":"suresh","designation":"designer","address":"fffswss","salary":"1212"},{"name":"suresh","designation":"tester","address":"he is from cheeran maanagar","salary":"20000"}]}
```

now im having problem with presenting in view i.e i dont know how to get the data via GetJson and run it in an $.each loop in jQuery where data is repersented in table..does any one have idea

been a whole night breaking my headoff with this and thanks for your help in advance ^^

Comment: like ? sorry im a bit novice with using json can you explain it a bit

Comment: $.JSON.parse(insert_your_JSON_here)`

Comment: ahh!! i see thank you very much

Comment: then do your `$.each()`

Comment: "encoded in a controller"? Be more specific.

Comment: yeah i encoded my array in the controller

Comment: @aldrin27 no need to parse when using `$.getJSON` it is done for you internally. Also there is no `$.JSON.parse()`

Comment: Ahh. Yes. Thank you @charlietfl `$.parseJSON()`

Comment: so that's why it aint working till now ...any other idea's to insert them in a table

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="table_container"></div>
```

**Javascript code**

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'index.php', // You will have to change here. Put your URL here
  success: function(jsonData){
    // In here the jsonData will look like this: 
    // jsonData = {"allk":[{"name":"raju","designation":"developer","address":"he is from viswasapuram","salary":"30000"},{"name":"bob","designation":"designer","address":"no idea","salary":"100000"},{"name":"bob","designation":"designer","address":"no idea","salary":"100000"},{"name":"suresh","designation":"designer","address":"fffswss","salary":"1212"},{"name":"suresh","designation":"tester","address":"he is from cheeran maanagar","salary":"20000"}]};

    var tblhtml = '<table class="table"><thead><tr><th>#</th><th>Name</th><th>Designation</th><th>Address</th><th>Salary</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
    for(i in jsonData.allk){
       var row = jsonData.allk[i];
       tblhtml += '<tr><td>'+ ++i +'</td><td>' + row.name + '</td><td>' + row.designation + '</td><td>' + row.address + '</td><td>' + row.salary + '</td></tr>';
    }
    tblhtml += '</tbody></table>';
    $('#table_container').html(tblhtml);
  }
});
```

Comment: jQuery.getJSON("http://localhost/example22/index.php?r=site/display",function(jsonData){
        jQuery.each(jsonData.allk,function(){
            var tbl = "<tr>";
            tbl +="<td>' ++i '</td>";
            tbl +="<td>' jsonData.allk.name '</td>";
            tbl +="<td>' jsonData.allk.designation  '</td>";
            tbl +="<td>' jsonData.allk.address '</td>";
            tbl +="<td>' jsonData.allk.salary '</td>";
            tbl += "</tr>";
            jQuery("#insertdata").append( tbl );
        });